# Issue while installing Ruby Rails on CentOs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems, centos

When iam trying to install Ruby Rails on my centos server .When i enter Bundle install i got the error

An error occurred while installing pg (0.14.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.14.1'` succeeds before bundling.

When i try `gem install pg -v '0.14.1 got the below error

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.14.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.14.1/ext/gem_make.out

Anybody know why i get this error? Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You are probably missing some libraries/dependencies. "Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.14.1/ext/gem_make.out" - have you tried looking there?

Comment: Can you also post all (or only the relevant parts) of `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.14.1/ext/gem_make.out`?

Answer (score 4):

This should help you --

```
$ sudo yum install postgresql-devel
Setting up Install Process
...
Complete!
$ sudo gem install pg
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed pg-0.14.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for pg-0.14.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for pg-0.14.1...
```

Comment: I had a similar problem (pg 9.3.1, CentOS 6.4, in my case system RVM) and this got me close.  After installing the postgresql-devel packack, I was able to build the gem, but only with `gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_config` (I was logged in as root, but I don't think that matters).  However I am still having problems building using bundler -- same error as @vks reports (and the gem_make.out has mostly the same information as reported).